# Different folder size after compression/decompression on different machines

Tags: filesystems, tar, compression

In a server migration (from old server A to new server B), I compressed the folder /home/user (size 620M, got with "du -sh") with the command

```
tar -zcpf user.tar.gz /home/user/ >> /log.txt
```

then I moved user.tar.gz to the new server by curl/ftp, gave the command

```
tar -xzf user.tar.gz -C /home/ >> /extract_log.txt
```

and the resulting /home/user/ directory has size equal to 625M!

How is it possibile? The number of files inside is the same, and if I check a different size folder (differences got with "ls -l" command), the files inside appear the same with "ls -l".
Is perhaps due to the different machines/hard drives? (home partitions are both ext4)

Comment: Disk usage isn't necessarily identical to file size. See eg http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/du-gives-two-different-results-for-the-same-file

Answer (score 1):

The files can all be identical, but take more space, if the new server has a larger block size, e.g. 8K instead of 4K.  The space a file takes is rounded up to an integral number of blocks.  That example would result in 4K more being taken up by about half of the files.